# OKTA OpenId Integration with Angular2, seems Okta service is not compatible with Angular2

Tags: angular, okta-api

When I am trying to redirect my application to the login page when any error is coming up from api while login it should redirect to the OKTA Login page again. But the page is keep on loading. I tried using Okta Service (@okta/okta-angular@1.0.7) to use isAuthenticated() method but seems it is not compatible with ANgular2. If anyone can suggest any solution for this would be a great help?

Comment: Are you using Angular version 2.0 or are you able to use a newer version like Angular 12 or 13? Our Angular quickstart works with Angular 13. https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/

Comment: @Matt We are using angular version 2

Comment: Okta only supports Angular 7 and above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/65681/matt-raible https://www.okta.com/integrations/stack-overflow-for-teams for generating code challenge also we are using OktaCryto-v3.1.min.js instead of PKCE. Similarly do we have any js to authorize user which we can use in Angular2?

Comment: You might be able to use our Auth JS library. This tutorial might help. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/12/secure-angular-login

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/65681/matt-raible